# Maximise $(\cos x\ln (x^{\frac1x})-\frac{\cos x\log_{10}x}{\ln(\ln x)})^{\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima, wolfram-alpha

[image]

Maximise $$\large \left(\cos x\ln (x^{\frac1x})-\frac{\cos x\log_{10}x}{\ln(\ln x)}\right)^{\cos x}$$

> I wonder why Mathematica says infinity as answer, but on desmos graph it is clear that it is less than 2

[image]

$\color{blue}{\text{Even WolframAlpha gave correct answer}}\color{red}{\text{ local maximum value as 1.461}}$

**My try:**

I used the command Maximise with and without constraints. I tried both using constaint as $\ln x >1$ But nothing correct come  up.

Next I also tried FindMaximum it didn't show anything either, but WolframAlpha command gave local maximum correctly.

**I wonder is there any analytical way to find $\color{green}{\text{Local Maximum Value ?}}$**

Answer (score 0):

Using Mathematica `NMaximize`, I obtained an almost immediate result for $1,000$ exact figures.
$$1.460697870308468497370818908815784175460033519589233153539805\cdots$$

Computing the derivative and expanding it as a series around $x=\frac {7\pi}2$gives as an *estimate* the solution of
$$\log \left(\frac{1}{7} \left(x-\frac{7 \pi }{2}\right) \log
   \left(\frac{7 \pi }{2}\right) \left(\frac{2}{\pi
   }-\frac{7}{\log (10) \log \left(\log \left(\frac{7 \pi
   }{2}\right)\right)}\right)\right)+1=0$$ which is $x=10.6174$ while the exact solution is $x=10.6062$.

Using the approximate solution, the maximum value is $1.46049$ while the exact solution is $x=1.46070$.